# How to print the public key of a certificate using keytool?

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

Is there a way in keytool to print the publick key of a certificate? I tried:

```
keytool -printcert -file client.crt
```

But it gives only the following information:

```
Owner: CN=client, OU=as, O=as, L=as, ST=as, C=as
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=as, CN=ca, OU=as, O=as, L=as, ST=as, C=as
Serial number: 3
Valid from: Tue Apr 10 12:18:47 GMT+05:30 2012 until: Wed Apr 10 12:18:47 GMT+05
:30 2013
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  26:C0:29:E9:8C:AB:C3:9E:95:38:74:8A:87:D3:86:8D
         SHA1: 5C:5A:BA:47:44:83:7E:CB:48:BE:DD:E5:39:51:24:42:C6:C5:60:8B
         SHA256: DA:26:B8:C8:F4:04:3E:62:F3:7F:3B:EC:1D:9F:85:66:28:00:45:55:66:
15:FF:BB:37:77:97:59:F0:EC:0B:B6
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 1
```

There is no public key in this.

Comment: There is a way to use keytool with -list option to do this, but the accepted answer says to use openssl. Please refer the answer by Vlad Sankin below.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do that With `openssl`.

If this certificate is DER-encoded (binary), use:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in client.crt -pubkey -noout
```

for PEM-encoded use `-inform pem` option (or no `-inform` at all).

To see details of public key, use:

```
openssl x509 -inform der -in client.crt -pubkey -noout | openssl rsa -pubin -text -noout
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am able to see the public key. But is there any way to do it in keytool?

Comment: There is a way to use keeytool with -list option to print, please refer answer from @Vlad Sankin

Answer (score 73):

You can do it with:

```
keytool -list -rfc -keystore mykeystore.jks -alias certificate_alias -storepass password
```

Example run:

```
PS c:\sample> keytool -list -rfc -keystore mykeystore.jks -alias cert_alias -storepass password
Alias name: cert_alias
Creation date: Apr 25, 2014
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: assuming openssl is not available and to answer the actual question (how to use keytool to print public key part).

Comment: The question asked how to print the public key of the certificate. This output is the PEM encoded representation of the entire certificate. Public Key output would start with '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----'

Comment: 2 years later I now realize @VladSankin was just describing how to get the certificate as a precursor to using openssl to extract the public key from it. So building on the accepted answer you could do something like `keytool -list -rfc -keystore mykeystore.jks -alias cert_alias -storepass password | openssl x509 -inform pem -pubkey -noout | openssl rsa -pubin -text -noout`

Comment: Why is the sample saying `PrivateKeyEntry` ? Is it the private key?

Comment: It would be wonderful if you mention the documentation and purpose of -rfc  argument of keytool

Comment: `-rfc` tells `keytool` to write the output certificate in `Base 64 encoding` form described in `RFC 1421 Certificate Encoding Standard`

Comment: thank you! `-rfc` looks like the option I am wanting

Answer (score 13):

You can print the cert to pem format, then use openssl to print public key from the pem format.

1. add `-rfc` option to -printcert

   keytool -printcert -rfc -file client.crt
2. save the output like below to a file client.pem

   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   MIIB4zCCAUygAwIBAgIIRzI14w7rL20wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQENBQAwMzELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDTAL

   ......

   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
3. then use openssl

   openssl x509 -inform pem   -text -in client.pem

so you got the public key

Comment: Without intermediate file: keytool -list -rfc --keystore ./path_to_keystore.jks | openssl x509 -inform pem -pubkey

Answer (score 8):

*Keytool list rfc* just prints the *base64 encoded* version of whole certificate, not the *public key*. Keytool doesn't support the printing the public key of Certificate. We can use *openssl* for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

```
keytool -export -alias myalias -keystore mystore.jks  | openssl x509 -inform der -pubkey -noout
```