# Make the publicKey Object from the loaded certificate

Tags: java, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have a certificate which I would like to use to encrypte some message. Now I am trying to load certificate from the file  but I do not know how to create
the PublicKey object. I want to create it use this methode to encrypte it.

I downloaded the certificate from this link:

https://dtc.jrc.ec.europa.eu/dtc_public_key_certificates.php

**Code**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PublicKey;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;


public class MakePublicKey {

    static byte[] signature = null;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            FileInputStream ecPubKeyFIS = new FileInputStream("D__TCC40-1.bin");

            try {
                int certificateLength = ecPubKeyFIS.available();
                byte[] certificate = new byte[certificateLength];
                ecPubKeyFIS.read(certificate);

                MakePublicKey.signature = new byte[128];
                System.arraycopy(certificate, 0, MakePublicKey.signature, 0, 128);

                // How can I make of the signature byte[] an  PublicKey Object to call the method as the following: encrypte("Hellow World!", pk)?


            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public static byte[] encrypte(String message, PublicKey pk) {

        Cipher cipher = null;
        byte[] encrypted = null;
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encrypted;

    }

}
```

**Edit**

When using the following snipt

```
                CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(ecPubKeyFIS);
            PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input
    at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:104)
    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
    at MakePublicKey.main(MakePublicKey.java:32)
```

Comment: Import it on keystore, then use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709265/get-public-key-from-imported-certificate-in-keystore-with-java . Do this help you?

Comment: @Jens I voted to undelete your answer. Nothing wrong with it except that you didn't store the public key into a variable. Not your fault the OP has a zero length download.

Comment: Following the link on that page to 'ERCA official documentation', the Certification Practices statement says in 1.1 Overview **The public key certificate format used by the digital tachograph is proprietary and incompatible with
the X.509 public key certificates** whose use is assumed, but not required, by IETF RFC 3647 [4]. Google found me someone redistributing a Norwegian document purportedly copying the EC spec; it's not clear to me if this is authorized or not.

Answer (score 0):

Read the certficate as a [X509Certificate.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/X509Certificate.html), and than you can call getPublicKey:

```
FileInputStream ecPubKeyFIS = new FileInputStream("D__TCC40-1.bin");
CertificateFactory cd = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate c=(X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(ecPubKeyFIS );
c.getPublicKey();
```

Comment: I have tried your could but  I am getting the following error: `java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input
 at sun.security.provider.X509Factory.engineGenerateCertificate(X509Factory.java:104)
 at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:339)
 at MakePublicKey.main(MakePublicKey.java:30)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Empty input`

Comment: Do not I need to extract the public key from the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the data as a `Certificate`, using the `CertificateFactory`class, and then call `getPublicKey()`.

This is all documented.

Comment: Please would you take a look at my edited part and tell me what I am doing wrong since I am reading the data as `Certificate` using the `CertificateFactory` and then calling the `getPublicKey`

Comment: I've read it. You have an empty input file, just as the exceptionon already told you hours ago. So fix that.