# When you uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate; do you have to use the same certificate?

Tags: android, google-play, android-studio-3.0

I am using Android Studio and am trying to build a signed apk. 
I am building a signed apk using the following steps:
Module -->app
KeyStorePath--> /Users/mshikher/Documents/SchoolCounter/app/Untitled
(SchoolCounter is name of the project).
After entering the keyStorePassword and keyPassword clicked NEXT.
Clicking on both the V1 and V2 versions clicked on Finish.
There was earlier an apk uploaded in the play.console by some other person, and now if I try to upload my apk into the production release I get this error.

```
You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
[ SHA1: AA:6F:D6:9E:72:B7:9B:C6:45:63:70:69:66:B4:DA:9B:72:6D:3D:23 ]
and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
[ SHA1: 88:5D:A7:91:A9:5B:2C:66:DD:ED:13:96:37:49:D6:B7:4D:1E:B0:09 ]
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.
```

I have changed the version number also in the build.gradle file:

```
versionName "2.0"
```

What should I do to upload my apk in the play.google.com ?

Comment: You must use the same keystore file which you used for the initial build.

Comment: You need the change not only version name but also version code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The apk must be signed with the same certificates as the previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843212/the-apk-must-be-signed-with-the-same-certificates-as-the-previous-version)

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you sign your apk with different Keystore.

You need to use the same keystore for all version you upload on playstore. Please sign your apk with the same keystore you have used to publish the last apk.

For more information please check this link : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: sckeystore.jks is the file given to me by the developer who had signed it before. Should i give the path of the keyStore path like this: 
/Users/mshikher/Documents/SchoolCounter/app/sckeystore.jks

Comment: No required. Only thing you have to make sure is keystore file should be same.

Comment: Make sure you have the same certificate. Can you print what public keys are in your keystore? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103657/how-to-print-the-public-key-of-a-certificate-using-keytool

If the certficate doesn't match like the error message says it doesn't then it won't work. If you really can't find the upload certificate Google Play Developer Support should be able to help you move to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing version name versionName "2.0" please change "versionCode" and "version name" both  to other so that you can upload it and second thing please select same .jks file

You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1.
you need to change version code.